# I want to show components in a column flow with styled components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I’m a newbie with react’s styled components

Why doesn’t the next code display the elements in a column fashion

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const CategoryButton = styled.button`
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
`
const categoryFilterContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`

function App() {
  var catArr = ['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3']
  return (
    <categoryFilterContainer>
      {catArr.map(category => {
        return (
          <CategoryButton>{category}</CategoryButton>
        )
      })}
    </categoryFilterContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

categoryFilterContainer is indicating that the flow direction is column

What am I doing wrong here

Rafael

Comment: can you share screenshot of output?

Comment: When you say "column fashion" do you mean as per `flex-direction: column;`, i.e. the 3 options stacked on top of each other? Or side by side, as in each option is its own column. Not too sure by your wording

Answer (score 2):

All React components you define [must start with a capital letter](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

So your container component `categoryFilterContainer` should be renamed `CategoryFilterContainer`, and then have

```
<CategoryFilterContainer>
  ...
</CategoryFilterContainer>
```

[You can see them in this sandbox stacking them vertically in a column format when the capitalization is fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-hvz22?file=/index.js)

Comment: Verified, this looks to be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to have the items displayed as three columns, then you're using the wrong CSS value for flex-direction.

`flex-direction: column` will place the items above each other.

`flex-direction: row` will place the items next to each other.

```css
.col, .row { display: flex }
.col { flex-direction: column }
.row { flex-direction: row }
```

```html
<p>flex-direction: column</p>
<div class="col">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>

<p>flex-direction: row</p>
<div class="row">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```